# Centering table column titles above comma-aligned numbers

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, best-practices

I am trying to make the following table look nice. With that I want the title 
to be centered horizontally, and the numbers to be alligned at comma.

Here is how it looks now:

[image: Table]

And my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}       % Alternativet er å bruke {report}, men vi holder oss helst til {article} i labrapportene.
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
table-number-alignment = right,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!tb]
    \centering
        \caption{beregnede og målte verdier av magnetfeltet $B$ på aksen til en kort spole s,f.a. avstanden $x$ fra spolens midtplan.}
        \vspace{0.5cm}                      % Litt ekstra plass for å få det til å se penere ut.
        \label{Tabell2}\resizebox{15cm}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}*{10}{r@{}}} 
            \toprule                        % Horisontal linje.     &
\multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{\centering {\color{white}|}\vspace*{-0.3cm} \newline \hspace*{0.1cm} $x$     \newline ($m$) }                   &    
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=2R$ \newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Beregnet   \newline \hspace*{0.3cm}  $B_1$       \newline (gauss)}  &   
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a= R$ \newline \hspace*{0.15cm} Beregnet   \newline \hspace*{0.25cm} $B_1$       \newline (gauss)}  &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=R/2$\newline \hspace*{0.15cm} Beregnet   \newline \hspace*{0.25cm} $B_1$       \newline (gauss)}  &    
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=2R$ \newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Målt       \newline \hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2$       \newline (gauss)}  &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=2R$ \newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Differanse \newline \hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2 - B_1$ \newline (\%}      &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a= R$ \newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Målt \newline\hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2$ \newline (prosent)}             &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a= R$ \newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Differanse \newline\hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2 - B_1$ \newline (\%)}      & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=R/2$\newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Målt \newline\hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2$ \newline (prosent)}             &
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\centering $a=R/2$\newline \hspace*{0.05cm} Differanse \newline\hspace*{0.1cm}  $B_2 - B_1$ \newline (\%)}       \\
\midrule                                        
-0,18   &  5,265    &  3,365    &  2,981    &  5,31     &  0,864    &  3,34     & -0,743    &  3,01     &  0,959 \\
-0,16   &  7,725    &  4,667    &  4,057    &  7,77     &  0,584    &  4,60     & -1,439    &  4,08     &  0,559 \\
-0,14   & 11,595    &  6,666    &  5,675    & 11,61     &  0,131    &  6,58     & -1,293    &  5,68     &  0,084 \\
-0,12   & 17,398    &  9,797    &  8,175    & 17,48     &  0,470    &  9,62     & -1,811    &  8,17     & -0,061 \\
-0,10   & 24,796    & 14,694    & 12,114    & 24,71     & -0,345    & 14,35     & -2,338    & 12,04     & -0,607 \\
-0,08   & 30,955    & 21,937    & 18,306    & 30,82     & -0,436    & 21,46     & -2,175    & 18,10     & -1,125 \\
-0,06   & 31,701    & 30,981    & 27,529    & 31,61     & -0,288    & 30,59     & -1,262    & 27,27     & -0,940 \\
-0,04   & 27,387    & 38,714    & 39,223    & 27,42     &  0,121    & 38,68     & -0,088    & 38,99     & -0,595 \\
-0,02   & 22,688    & 41,914    & 49,688    & 22,67     & -0,080    & 42,49     &  1,375    & 49,85     &  0,326 \\
 0,00   & 20,852    & 42,202    & 53,852    & 20,74     & -0,538    & 43,00     &  1,892    & 54,31     &  0,850 \\
 0,02   & 22,688    & 41,914    & 49,688    & 22,49     & -0,873    & 42,46     &  1,303    & 50,04     &  0,708 \\
 0,04   & 27,387    & 38,714    & 39,223    & 27,00     & -1,412    & 39,01     &  0,764    & 39,36     &  0,349 \\
 0,06   & 31,701    & 30,981    & 27,529    & 31,42     & -0,887    & 31,16     &  0,578    & 27,63     &  0,368 \\
 0,08   & 30,955    & 21,937    & 18,306    & 31,00     &  0,145    & 22,06     &  0,560    & 18,41     &  0,568 \\
 0,10   & 24,796    & 14,694    & 12,114    & 25,13     &  1,348    & 14,88     &  1,269    & 12,15     &  0,301 \\
 0,12   & 17,398    &  9,797    &  8,175    & 17,83     &  2,482    &  9,89     &  0,945    &  8,26     &  1,040 \\
 0,14   & 11,595    &  6,666    &  5,675    & 11,91     &  2,718    &  6,77     &  1,558    &  5,74     &  1,141 \\
 0,16   &  7,725    &  4,667    &  4,057    &  8,00     &  3,561    &  4,74     &  1,561    &  4,13     &  1,792 \\
 0,18   &  5,265    &  3,365    &  2,981    &  5,39     &  2,384    &  3,45     &  2,526    &  3,04     &  1,965 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Yeah, it is not a pretty sight. I think I have tried every single mean I have to make it look good.
Like using the `siunitx` package and so on.

So yeah, any help in making this table look good is greatly appreciated.

My main problem and question is how to make the title be centered above the numbers, and having the numbers align at comma / alligned to the right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I note that you're trying to make the nine data columns all have the same width. That's not straightforward to do if one one also wants to use the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package.

To provide a workable solution, one can start by observing that the word "Differanse" is the longest word in any of the columns; by providing code in the "non-Differanse" columns that forces them to occupy the width of the "Differanse", one can achieve the equal-column-width objective. The MWE below builds on these observations to achieve your objective.

Note that when you're dealing with an `S` column type, material that's enclosed in curly braces will be centered by default. Hence, if you want to center-typeset some non-numeric material, say "xyz", in the respective S column, it's not necessary to provide a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{xyz}` wrapper -- all that's needed is `{xyz}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs,color,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

% set margins to whatever specifications are correct...
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ table-number-alignment = right,
          output-decimal-marker = {,} ,
          table-format=2.3}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default is 5pt

% set up some auxiliary variables and macros
\newsavebox\diffbox
   \sbox\diffbox{Differanse}
\newlength\diffwidth
   \setlength\diffwidth{\wd\diffbox}
\newsavebox\Berbox
   \savebox{\Berbox}[\diffwidth][c]{\begingroup Beregnet\endgroup}
\newsavebox\Maltbox
   \savebox{\Maltbox}[\diffwidth][c]{\begingroup Målt\endgroup}

% Now the commands to typeset the words "Beregnet" and "Malt" in 
% "boxes" that are as wide as the word "Differanse"
\newcommand{\Beregnet}{\usebox{\Berbox}}
\newcommand{\Malt}{\usebox{\Maltbox}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!tb]
\caption{Beregnede og målte verdier av magnetfeltet $B$ på aksen til 
  en kort spole s,f.a. avstanden $x$ fra spolens midtplan.}
\label{Tabell2}

\vspace{0.5cm}\noindent  % Litt ekstra plass for å få det til å se penere ut.
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2] *{9}{S}}
\toprule
& {$a=2R$} & {$a=R$} & {$a=R/2$} 
& {$a=2R$} & {$a=2R$} & {$a=R$} 
& {$a=R$} & {$a=R/2$} & {$a=R/2$}\\
& \Beregnet  & \Beregnet & \Beregnet 
& \Malt & {Differanse} & \Malt 
& {Differanse} & \Malt & {Differanse} \\
{$x$}
& {$B_1$} & {$B_1$} & {$B_1$} 
& {$B_2$} & {$B_2-B_1$} & {$B_2$} 
& {$B_2-B_1$} & {$B_2$} & {$B_2-B_1$} \\
{(m)} % don't set in italics
& {(gauss)} & {(gauss)} & {(prosent)} 
& {(gauss)} & {(\%)} & {(gauss)} 
& {(\%)} & {(prosent)} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
-0,18 & 5,265 & 3,365 & 2,981 & 5,31 & 0,864 & 3,34 & -0,743 & 3,01 & 0,959 \\
-0,16 & 7,725 & 4,667 & 4,057 & 7,77 & 0,584 & 4,60 & -1,439 & 4,08 & 0,559 \\
-0,14 & 11,595 & 6,666 & 5,675  & 11,61 & 0,131 & 6,58 & -1,293 & 5,68 & 0,084 \\
-0,12 & 17,398 & 9,797 & 8,175 & 17,48 & 0,470 & 9,62 & -1,811 & 8,17 & -0,061 \\
-0,10 & 24,796 & 14,694 & 12,114 & 24,71 & -0,345 & 14,35 & -2,338 & 12,04 & -0,607 \\
-0,08 & 30,955 & 21,937 & 18,306 & 30,82 & -0,436 & 21,46 & -2,175 & 18,10 & -1,125 \\
-0,06 & 31,701 & 30,981 & 27,529 & 31,61 & -0,288 & 30,59 & -1,262 & 27,27 & -0,940 \\
-0,04 & 27,387 & 38,714 & 39,223 & 27,42 & 0,121 & 38,68 & -0,088 & 38,99 & -0,595 \\
-0,02 & 22,688 & 41,914 & 49,688 & 22,67 & -0,080 & 42,49 & 1,375 & 49,85 & 0,326 \\
 0,00 & 20,852 & 42,202 & 53,852 & 20,74 & -0,538 & 43,00 & 1,892 & 54,31 & 0,850 \\
 0,02 & 22,688 & 41,914 & 49,688 & 22,49 & -0,873 & 42,46 & 1,303 & 50,04 & 0,708 \\
 0,04 & 27,387 & 38,714 & 39,223 & 27,00 & -1,412 & 39,01 & 0,764 & 39,36 & 0,349 \\
 0,06 & 31,701 & 30,981 & 27,529 & 31,42 & -0,887 & 31,16 & 0,578 & 27,63 & 0,368 \\
 0,08 & 30,955 & 21,937 & 18,306 & 31,00 & 0,145 & 22,06 & 0,560 & 18,41 & 0,568 \\
 0,10 & 24,796 & 14,694 & 12,114 & 25,13 & 1,348 & 14,88 & 1,269 & 12,15 & 0,301 \\
 0,12 & 17,398 & 9,797 & 8,175 & 17,83 & 2,482 & 9,89 & 0,945 & 8,26 & 1,040 \\
 0,14 & 11,595 & 6,666 & 5,675 & 11,91 & 2,718 & 6,77 & 1,558 & 5,74 & 1,141 \\
 0,16 & 7,725 & 4,667 & 4,057 & 8,00 & 3,561 & 4,74 & 1,561 & 4,13 & 1,792 \\
 0,18 & 5,265 & 3,365 & 2,981 & 5,39 & 2,384 & 3,45 & 2,526 & 3,04 & 1,965 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}} % end of scope of \resizebox command
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this suggestion, but a short question before accepting this. Is there any work around to avoid using '\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}' ? This tabe is part of a longer physics repport that contains several tables. Forcing the tablewidth globaly makes the table seem awkward =)

Comment: Sorry for the late edit: But I had problems with another very similar table. It is far from being worthy of its own question. Where is my mistake? I thought I did this exactly as yours. Although it is only the last coloumn that is wrong http://pastebin.com/3jTu4ctj

Comment: Regarding your first question: To keep the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` local to a specific tabular environment, just remove it from the preamble and reinsert it between the `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}` statements; that way, its scope ends when LaTeX encounters the next `\end{table}` statement. By the way, in your original code you have 10 [!] `r@{}` column type specifiers; the `@{}` part removes half of the intercolumn whitespace, hence you'd be down to `2.5pt` of whitespace anyway. Not that different from the `3pt` whitespace I suggest in my example.

Comment: Regarding your second question: For the second tabular environment, you should replace `\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2] *{7}{S}}` with `\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2] *{5}{S} S[table-format=2.9]}`. (You have only 7 columns in total.) By the way, I can't help but wonder what the use may be of showing 9 digits after the decimal in the final column given that it's a difference of two quantities whose precision would appear to be no better than 3 digits after the decimal?

Answer (score 6):

A first approximation is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\newcommand\my[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % just to simplify input

\centering

\caption{beregnede og målte verdier av magnetfeltet $B$ på aksen til
en kort spole s, f.a. avstanden $x$ fra spolens midtplan.}\label{Tabell2}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{S[table-format=3.3]}} 
\toprule
& \my{$a=2R$} & \my{$a=R$} & \my{$a=R/2$} & \my{$a=2R$} & \my{$a=2R$} &
  \my{$a=R$}  & \my{$a=R$} & \my{$a=R/2$} & \my{$a=R/2$} \\
& \my{Beregnet} & \my{Beregnet} & \my{Beregnet} &
\my{Mål} & \my{Differanse} & 
\my{Mål} & \my{Differanse} & 
\my{Mål} & \my{Differanse}\\
\my{$x$} & \my{$B_1$} & \my{$B_1$} & \my{$B_1$} & \my{$B_2$} &
\my{$B_2 - B_1$} & \my{$B_2$} & \my{$B_2 - B_1$} & \my{$B_2$} & \my{$B_2 - B_1$} \\
\my{(\si{m})} &
\my{(\si{gauss})} &   
\my{(\si{gauss})} &
\my{(\si{gauss})} &    
\my{(\si{gauss})} &
\my{(\%)} &
\my{(prosent)} &
\my{(\%)} & 
\my{(prosent)} &
\my{(\%)} \\
\midrule                                          
-0,18   &  5,265    &  3,365    &  2,981    &  5,31     &  0,864    &  3,34     & -0,743    &  3,01     &  0,959 \\
-0,16   &  7,725    &  4,667    &  4,057    &  7,77     &  0,584    &  4,60     & -1,439    &  4,08     &  0,559 \\
-0,14   & 11,595    &  6,666    &  5,675    & 11,61     &  0,131    &  6,58     & -1,293    &  5,68     &  0,084 \\
-0,12   & 17,398    &  9,797    &  8,175    & 17,48     &  0,470    &  9,62     & -1,811    &  8,17     & -0,061 \\
-0,10   & 24,796    & 14,694    & 12,114    & 24,71     & -0,345    & 14,35     & -2,338    & 12,04     & -0,607 \\
-0,08   & 30,955    & 21,937    & 18,306    & 30,82     & -0,436    & 21,46     & -2,175    & 18,10     & -1,125 \\
-0,06   & 31,701    & 30,981    & 27,529    & 31,61     & -0,288    & 30,59     & -1,262    & 27,27     & -0,940 \\
-0,04   & 27,387    & 38,714    & 39,223    & 27,42     &  0,121    & 38,68     & -0,088    & 38,99     & -0,595 \\
-0,02   & 22,688    & 41,914    & 49,688    & 22,67     & -0,080    & 42,49     &  1,375    & 49,85     &  0,326 \\
 0,00   & 20,852    & 42,202    & 53,852    & 20,74     & -0,538    & 43,00     &  1,892    & 54,31     &  0,850 \\
 0,02   & 22,688    & 41,914    & 49,688    & 22,49     & -0,873    & 42,46     &  1,303    & 50,04     &  0,708 \\
 0,04   & 27,387    & 38,714    & 39,223    & 27,00     & -1,412    & 39,01     &  0,764    & 39,36     &  0,349 \\
 0,06   & 31,701    & 30,981    & 27,529    & 31,42     & -0,887    & 31,16     &  0,578    & 27,63     &  0,368 \\
 0,08   & 30,955    & 21,937    & 18,306    & 31,00     &  0,145    & 22,06     &  0,560    & 18,41     &  0,568 \\
 0,10   & 24,796    & 14,694    & 12,114    & 25,13     &  1,348    & 14,88     &  1,269    & 12,15     &  0,301 \\
 0,12   & 17,398    &  9,797    &  8,175    & 17,83     &  2,482    &  9,89     &  0,945    &  8,26     &  1,040 \\
 0,14   & 11,595    &  6,666    &  5,675    & 11,91     &  2,718    &  6,77     &  1,558    &  5,74     &  1,141 \\
 0,16   &  7,725    &  4,667    &  4,057    &  8,00     &  3,561    &  4,74     &  1,561    &  4,13     &  1,792 \\
 0,18   &  5,265    &  3,365    &  2,981    &  5,39     &  2,384    &  3,45     &  2,526    &  3,04     &  1,965 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Check the documentation of `siunitx` for fine tuning the column specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue today.

I used `\hspace{1ex}` where there was a number "missing". Doing so I could use center alignment without any troubles. It works before a number (i.e. 17.23 in a column with numbers like 133.23) and behind the number (i.e. 0.23 and 0.235).

You might want to define a new command like `\newcommand{\x}{\hspace{1ex}}` for this, because using `\hspace{1ex}` all the time makes your code difficult to read.

**EDIT:**
A better solution is to use phantom characters like `\phantom{0}`. Doing so LaTeX adds an invisible character with the same height and width as the character you specify (in this case a zero). `\vphantom` and `\hpantom`also exist. They work the same as `\phantom` but only in the Vertical and Horizontal direction.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)