# Improve legibility in a siunitx table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, best-practices, siunitx

I am a rather basic user of LaTeX, so please be kind. ;)

I am using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to align numbers on tables, and this is a rather similar question to this one: [Centering table column titles above comma-aligned numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51779/centering-table-column-titles-above-comma-aligned-numbers).

However, my problem is first that I have quite long descriptions with different lengths on the first column, and second that numbers are both in absolute and percent values - absolute values being huge. The result is a neat table, although legibility is not the best.

I am writing to know if someone has suggestions on how I could (i) align to the left the descriptions of the first column, and (ii) improve the legibility of the 1900 and 2000 data, for example by inserting vertical lines or different table columns separators.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs,color,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ table-number-alignment = center,
  output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{15pt}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption[A simple table.]{A simple table with some layout problems I cannot solve.}
\label{tab:table}

\begin{tabular}{{S[table-format=10.1]}*{6}{S}}

{Some long description} & {Absolute} & {\% to the} & {Absolute} & {\% to the} & {\% of} \\
& {values} & {total} & {values} & {total} & {variation} \\
& {in 1900} & {amount in 1900} & {in 2000} & {amount in 2000} &{ 1900--2000} \\ \hline

{Some very very long description} & 10000 & 1,5 & 10000 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
{Some very long description} & 200000 & 11,5  & 200000 & 11,5  & 1,5 \\
{Some long description} & 450000 & 1,5  & 450000 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
{Some very very long description} & 45000000 & 11,5  & 4500000 & 11,5 & 1,5  \\ \hline
{Some description} & 12345678 & 1,5 & 12345678 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
{Some long description} & 123456789 & 11,5  & 123456789 & 11,5 & 1,5  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I have tried several options many times and looked at the `siunitx` package, however despite my efforts this is the best I could get.

I thank in advance anyone who is willing to give some time to help me and I will be very grateful for any helpful suggestion.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), but your code does not compile for me: `Paragraph ended before \end was complete.` I have fixed it now, but in the future please make sure that the code posted compiles.

Comment: For the first column, you don't need `S` but `l`. And for the rest, instead of `*{6}{S}` you should tell `siunitx` what format do you need: `S[table-format = 9.0] S[table-format = 2.1] S[table-format = 9.0] S[table-format = 2.1] S[table-format = 1.1]`. I'm not a “pro” of this package, so may be this is not the best way. Remember, I'm not solving your problems but suggesting better ideas. By the way, you could take a look at `booktabs` package and use `\midrule` instead of `\hline`.

Comment: Hello! Thanks to both, the suggestions have been highly useful.The l instead of the S improved the legibility of the table, and so did the \midrule. Thanks! Strange however that the MWE did not work, I've checked it before posting it..anyway thanls again!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you do the following:

- For the first column, don't use `S` -- `l` (left-aligned text column) will do just fine.
- For columns 2 and 4, instead of just specifying `S`, maybe specify `S[table-format=10.2]`.
- Simplify the generation of landscape-oriented tables by using the `sidewaystable` environment (provided by the `rotating` package).
- Since you're already loading the `booktabs` package, you might as well use that package's commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of the plain `\hline` instruction.

Here's what the resulting table will look like -- note that there' no need for going to `\footnotesize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs,color,rotating}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption[A simple table.]{A simple table with some layout problems I cannot solve.} \label{tab:table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=10.2] S S[table-format=10.2] SS @{}}
\toprule
Some long description & {Absolute} & {\% to the} & {Absolute} & {\% to the} & {\% of} \\
& {values} & {total} & {values} & {total} & {variation} \\
& {in 1900} & {amount in 1900} & {in 2000} & {amount in 2000} &{ 1900--2000} \\ 
\midrule
Some very very long description & 10000 & 1,5 & 10000 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
Some very long description & 200000 & 11,5  & 200000 & 11,5  & 1,5 \\
Some long description & 450000 & 1,5  & 450000 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
Some very very long description & 45000000 & 11,5  & 4500000 & 11,5 & 1,5  \\ 
\midrule
Some description & 12345678 & 1,5 & 12345678 & 1,5  & 1,5  \\
Some long description & 123456789 & 11,5  & 123456789 & 11,5 & 1,5  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer. The sidewaystable command is really good and its works better than landscape, especially for printing. I have however some longtables that I still have to fix, but I think I will keep the landscape for those. Thanks again